# Multithreading program collapses system

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

I am making a multi-threading port scanner program in Java. The code is as follows:

```
final class MultiThrImpl extends Thread {
    private Thread t;
    final private String threadName;
    final private String host;
    final private int port;

    MultiThrImpl(String name, String host, int port) {
        this.threadName = name;
        // Initialize the host and port to scan
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        // System.out.println("Creating " + threadName );
    }

    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Running " +  threadName );
        String text;
           try {
                Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
                text = host + " is listening on port " + port;
                System.out.println(text);
                socket.close();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.out.println("The IP address of the host " + "could not be determined");
                System.exit(1);
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                System.out.println(
                        "A security manager exists " + "and its checkConnect method doesn't allow the operation.");
                System.exit(1);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("The port parameter is outside the specified range of valid port values, "
                        + "which is between 0 and 65535, inclusive");
                System.exit(1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Every time a port that is closed is found an IO Exception is thrown
                // Commented out so not to pollute the console output
                /*
                 * System.out.println("An IO exception has occured");
                 * System.exit(1);
                 */
            }
            System.out.println("Terminating " + threadName);
       }

    public void start() {
        //System.out.println("Starting " + threadName);
        if (t == null) {
            t = new Thread(this, threadName);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}

final public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host;
        String text;
        final int secToSleep = 2;
        final int maxNumofThr = 10;
        // if not exactly one host is not given
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Please give the name of the host to scan as " + "a parameter to the program");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        host = args[0];
        MultiThrImpl T1;
        int port = 0;
        int numOfThreads = 0;
        // loop for all ports
        while (port < 65535) {

            T1 = new MultiThrImpl("Thread " + port, host, port);
            T1.start();

            numOfThreads++;
            // Do not let the program make more than maxNumofThr threads
            if (numOfThreads >= maxNumofThr) {
                System.out.println("Reached " + numOfThreads + " pausing");
                while (true) {
                    // Check that the last created thread has terminated
                    if (!T1.isAlive()) {
                        numOfThreads = 0;
                        System.out.println("About to continue execution");
                        break;
                    }
                    // sleep for 2 seconds
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(secToSleep);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        System.out.println("Interrupted while sleeping - Terminating to debug");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }
            port++;
        }
    }
}
```

While the program starts fine after some time has passed the whole IDE collapses. To my understanding Garbage Collector cannot collect the objects fast enough. Is my understanding of the problem correct? If so what can i do to battle this?

Comment: Did you just override `Thread.start()` with your own implementation?

Comment: @Kayaman I got the original idea from [here] (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm)

Comment: What do you mean by 'the whole IDE collapses'? Eclipse runs your program in a separate JVM so it does not affect Eclipse memory.

Comment: Well, it's completely wrong. I recommend you don't read anything from there. Instead read a proper tutorial from [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: You misread the tutorial, it uses a `Runnable`, it doesn't extend `Thread`.

Comment: @Kayaman search for the following in the tutorial **Create a Thread by Extending a Thread Class**

Comment: while (port < 65535)-> one thread per port? that is beyond "a lot"

Comment: @J.Doo No. I don't read tutorials written by incompetent people, and neither should you.

Comment: @efekctive why you say that? The thread finishes almost instantly

Comment: @J.Doo Kayaman is right, that is a *terrible*, *terrible* tutorial.

Comment: Look you asked a question. You are getting answers. How many quad cores would you need to have 64K threads running?

Comment: @efekctive i am not letting more than 5 threads run at the same time. Please check my code. Also thank you for you time as everyone too

Comment: Well that is not working either because my laptop which is quite old can handle 1500+ threads before collapsing. You need to rethink this

Answer (score 2):

You're overriding `Thread.start()` in your `MultiThrImpl` class, meaning that every time you call `T1.start()` a thread is created, but not started. Then you create another thread inside `start()`, which you **do** start. This eventually causes you to run out of resources as the unstarted threads can't be collected.

Instead of extending `Thread`, have your `MultiThrImpl` implement `Runnable` instead. The class contains a lot of unnecessary things (such as a thread's name, which can already be set through `Thread` class).

Answer (score 2):

It would make sense to wrap the port scanning task into a `Runnable` instead of spawning raw tasks and submitting them to a bounded `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20)`. This will ensure you are not running out of CPU/RAM and also simplify your code quite a lot.